# Solr post files for deleting documents

Tags: solr

I want to delete some documents from solr using `bin/post` command

I am trying to delete json documents. here is my file `tobedeleted.json` with ids

```
{"delete": ["1219073", "2234630", "120270", "244755", "2275454", "2121923", "2280254", "2261038", "1232067", "1227748"]}
```

I am using 
`/solr/bin/post -c mycore -d tobedeleted.json`

but it is throwing error as

```
    java -classpath /opt/solr/dist/solr-core-6.1.0.jar -Dauto=yes -Dc=projects -Ddata=args org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool /home/ansible/aws/data/DL_PT_20171205_20.json
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
POSTing args to http://localhost:8983/solr/projects/update...
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 (Bad Request) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/projects/update
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">1</int></lst><lst name="error"><lst name="metadata"><str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str><str name="root-error-class">com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException</str></lst><str name="msg">Unexpected character '/' (code 47) in prolog; expected '&lt;'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]</str><int name="code">400</int></lst>
</response>
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/projects/update
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/projects/update...
Time spent: 0:00:00.021
You have mail in /var/spool/mail/ansible
```

Please, can you let me know how can I delete documents using post utility?

Answer (score 0):

I have done workaround for it using curl. But if anybody have better solution please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You could try by creating a bash script. Put the document ids inside an array. Then loop the document ids using the following bin/post command:

```
bin/post -c "collection name" -d '<delete><id>"document id"</id></delete>'
```

Ex: `bin/post -c gettingstarted -d '<delete><id>42</id></delete>'`

(from https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/post-tool.html)

One word of advice, as I had issues with the post tool yesterday: restart your Zookeeper and then your Solr ensembles before you proceed using the post tool.

All the best!